# Iterating months using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a very weird requirement where I need to deal with months. Here is what I am try to do actually. I have two object say

```
jan_start_date=Time.parse("2012-01-01 00:00:00")
jan_end_date=Time.parse("2012-01-31 23:59:59")
```

I take this two datetime objects and iterate over feb, mar, april and soon to get some data.

Then I will take feb start and end dates and iterate over march, april and soon.

Its like month on month data collection. Once I am done with say Jan data, I need to take Feb's data and so on and so forth. How do I achieve this. Since I need to iterate over months.

Kindly help me out

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActiveSupport` has [beginning_of_month](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Date/Calculations/beginning_of_month) and [end_of_month](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Date/Calculations/end_of_month):

```
d = Date.today
#=> Fri, 13 Jul 2012
d.beginning_of_month
#=> Sun, 01 Jul 2012
d.end_of_month
#=> Tue, 31 Jul 2012
```

You can use [Date#>>](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-3E-3E) to shift dates forward monthwise:

```
(d>>2).end_of_month
#=> Sun, 30 Sep 2012
(d>>4).beginning_of_month
#=> Thu, 01 Nov 2012
```

Comment: Or use `d + 1.month` to shift months